# Selenium IDE doesn't do anything for "pause" command

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide, pause

I'm using the selenium IDE for Chrome on Mac Big Sur.  I want to add a puse in between commands to see why something isn't executing properly.  This is in my ".side" file

```
}, {
  "id": "32f35ed7-1a28-4540-a93d-3cb8ba0e012a",
  "comment": "",
  "command": "pause",
  "target": "",
  "targets": [],
  "value": "100000"
}, {
```

I have put a really high value but when I play back my test, it just breezes through it without pausing at all, although it tells me the command was successfully run

[image]

What's the right way to pause my test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Target instead of Value, Like below

```
Target: 100000
```

instead of

```
value: 100000
```

Also,

Set speed to fastest `(Actions --> Fastest`), otherwise it won't work.